# How to bind the visibility of label through a method

Tags: c#, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have several labels.i need set visiblity true or false several time.in case doing this my code is duplicating how to overcome this with mvvm

```
                userlabel.IsVisible = false;
                passwordlabel.IsVisible = false;
                userlabel1.IsVisible = true;
                passwordlabel1.IsVisible = true;
```

in my code this code of line reapiting several time. i need to put this in to method in my view model cs

Comment: Who do you have this `userlabel.IsVisible = false;` if you are using mvvm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could set the value of your properties in your ViewModel class and binding them to your view. In the example, for clarity, I am using a Base ViewModel that will rise the NotifyPropertyChanged event.

```
 public class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {

        private bool _isUserLabelVisible = false;

        public bool IsUserLabelVisible
        {
            get
            {
                return _isUserLabelVisible;
            }

            set
            {
                Set(ref _isUserLabelVisible, value);
            }
        }


        private bool _isPasswordVisible = true;

        public bool IsPasswordLabelVisible
        {
            get
            {
                return _isPasswordVisible;
            }

            set
            {
                Set(ref _isPasswordVisible, value);
            }
        }

        private void DisableAll()
        {
            IsPasswordLabelVisible = false;
            IsUserLabelVisible = false;
        }

        private void EnableAll()
        {
            IsUserLabelVisible = true;
            IsPasswordLabelVisible = true;
        }
    }
```

In this way you could create your methods and the view will be updated.
In your view you will need to use the BooleanToVisibilityConverter.

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow54741515.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:ignore="http://www.galasoft.ch/ignore"
        mc:Ignorable="d ignore"
        Height="300"
        Width="300"
        Title="MVVM Light Application"
        DataContext="{Binding Main, Source={StaticResource Locator}}">

    <Window.Resources>
        <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BoolToVis"/>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <TextBlock Name="userLabel" FontSize="36"
                   FontWeight="Bold"
                   Foreground="Purple"
                   Text="Username"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   Visibility="{Binding IsUserLabelVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"/>

        <TextBlock Name="passwordLabel" FontSize="36"
                   FontWeight="Bold"
                   Foreground="Purple"
                   Text="Password"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   Visibility="{Binding IsPasswordLabelVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Hope that this help.